# F# SQLProvider - Assign NULL values to fields

Tags: database, f#, type-providers

I'm loading data from an API, where certain fields have `NULL` values - which is expected. After I load the data (objects) into the list, I'm iterating over the list and storing each object into the database using [SQLProvider](https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider).

```
for x in myList do
    let item = db.Dbo.Item.Create()
    item.Name <- x.Name
    item.Description <- x.Description // Description might be NULL

db.SubmitUpdates()
```

However, this fails with the error saying that not all query parameter values are supplied.

As a workaround I now do this below, but it gets really annoying on the tables with a lot of columns.

```
if x.Description |> isNull |> not then
    item.Description <- x.Description
```

Is there a way to avoid this null-check?

Comment: I think the piping is a bit excessive here, e.g. `if not (isNull xx) then (doSomething with xx)` is easier on the eyes. However some of the approaches you could try would be 1. filter myList so that it doesn't have null x in it, 2. if you use SQLprovider, you could try turning the use Optionals option on, so you'd deal with Some/None, and then you could you List.choose for example to filter and map on the Some values.

Comment: @s952163 Filtering out is not really acceptable. I'm dealing with dozens of columns and most of them can be nullable. Nonexistence of values in some columns is valid scenario and I should be able to simply get the data from source fields into target DB columns w/o any checks.

Comment: Maybe the `useOpTypes = true` parameter mentioned in the other question might help you. I load a lot of the data into nullable columns, how you treat it depends, on where it comes from, if the data is actually nullable you could use `.GetValueOrDefault()`, so `x.Description.GetValueOrDefault()` on it, there's also `Uncheked.defaultof<_>`. Ideally it would be taken care of in the DTO.

Comment: How many rows are there? Executing a separate INSERT command for each record can hurt performance a *LOT*. It will be N times slower than a bulk inser or `INSERT VALUES` operation, especially for a small number of records

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Number of records is not big - otherwise I'd reach for DataTable/SqlBulkInsert. I prefer having elegant, readable code in this case.

Answer (score 2):

F# and the SQL Type provider try to use Option instead of Nullable.
I usually have a small function for converting Null into None and value into Some value.
For more details on the topic see [FSharp for fun and profit](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/).